# Should tables with very large records quantities be split into multiple tables

Tags: oracle

I'm working on an application (asp.net) that deals with a very high record count -- let's estimate about 75 million events per year coming in fairly evenly throughout the year, and each of these events generates up to 10 individual charges, for a total of about 750 million charges per year. At this point we're about 1/2 that volume but it will increase over the next few years.

We are currently using Oracle with one table for all of the charges and other tables with as many or fewer records. User count is not too high, and user-generated queries are rare. On the other hand, the application and its processing are running all the time, parsing source data and loading it into the tables.

I was looking for some hosting advice (if anyone has any comments on this here please feel free...) and someone mentioned it was a bad idea to have hundreds of millions of records in a single table, and that I should be splitting across multiple tables.

Is this absolutely true?

Thanks

Comment: as with everything..."it depends" If you read microsoft literature, sql server can handle terabytes of data. There are many strategies for dealing with large data such as filegroups, partitions, and indexing.

Comment: It depends on how you use the data. Fwiw, though, in the DB world you can think of 100kB at tiny, 1MB as small, 1GB as medium, 1TB as large, and 1PT as huge.

Comment: It's most certainly not "absolutely true."  Splitting tables can cause problems of its own, as queries should (arguably) never have to blur the line between object identifiers and data... the name of the table where a given row will be found should not typically be something you ever have to construct (e.g. a "transactions_2014" table, for transactions in a particular year, 2014).

Comment: My initial reaction is that you should look into partitioning the table. [Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25523/partition.htm). Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

If you have advanced partitioning and can partition by date range and sub partition by charge, then you can reduce the amount of logical IO required to get to your data, provided that you are doing date range based searches that mostly use charge to filter. If you don't have advanced partitioning, you can still partition it your self, but will have a higher level of complexity to replicate what Oracle will sell you. As with anything look at the trade offs and see what make sense. 75 million rows is a lot, but not unheard of and Oracle should certainly be able to manage that amount of data.

Ideally you want to avoid full table scans of 75 million records given the high cost in terms of logical IO. You also want to partition so that you don't have global indexes if at all possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you are mostly loading the data, and seldom querying it, then no need to split the table.  Any "home-grown" attempt at splitting the table is bound to cause grief; use Oracle's (extra-cost) partitioning option if your queries are usually date-ranged; but be careful; partitioning does not necessarily improve performance.  It can if the queries include critera that are the same as the partitioning criteria.

It does come in handy for archiving and purging old data; if your business rules are such that you don't need to retain the charge details beyond say 3 years or whatever.  With some appropriate indexes, even without partitioning, you should get good results querying millions of rows.

You do not mention whether your users (or the loading process) are complaining of long response time or load time.  It will come down to monitoring the database using tools such as the Automatic Workload Repository to determine where your bottlenecks are, and how to resolve them.  If you are looking for future issues, look at whether the charge detail data can be summarized after xx years, etc. and purge old data after it is summarized.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely, "splitting" your tables will improve your time response, will reduce memory usage, etc.

You can read about this technique (Sharding) in [wikipedia (Shard)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29).

A really [good article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/dsl/white-php-part2-355138.html) was written by Eli White, based on real-world experiences at Digg, TripAdvisor, and other high-traffic sites.

Comment: no, that is wrong, you can't say splitting your table will definitely improve performance and resource consumption. The only thing you can definitely say is that it will make the design more complex so it really makes sense to check very thoroughly if there is an improvement of performance.